# Inverting a monotone polynomial

Tags: polynomials, roots, inverse-function, monotone-functions

I have a polynomial of degree 5
$$f(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + a_3 x^3 + a_4 x^4 + a_5 x^5$$
that is strictly increasing (the derivative is always greater than zero). I would like to (approximately) invert this polynomial, i.e. find $f^{-1}$ such that $f^{-1}(f(x)) = x$. I know that $f^{-1}$ is unique and well-defined on all of $\mathbb{R}$ because of monotonicty of $f(x)$.

One possible solution that I'm aware of is to compute the inverse $f^{-1}(y)$ by finding the real root of the polynomial $p(x) = f(x) - y$ using e.g. Newton's method.
$$f(x) = y \iff f(x) - y = 0$$
Do there exists alternative **non-iterative** approaches for (approximately) solving this problem? Is it possible to approximate $f^{-1}$ given the coefficients $a_i$?

Comment: An issue is that the inverse function need not be a polynomial - for example if you take $f(x)=x^2$, then its inverse is $f^{-1}(x)=\sqrt{x}$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/701061/is-there-a-way-of-approximating-a-polynomials-inverse

Comment: @Nurator, thank you, I am aware of that question. However, the answers there mostly talk about (1) existence of the inverse (which definitely exists in my case) and (2) iterative methods for finding the inverse

Comment: Can you specify perhaps what kind of approximation you want, e.g. by a polynomial, in what regime e.g. x large, x small?

Comment: Approximation in terms of any closed-form expression (as defined in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression) would be great. I am concerned with "small" values of $x$ (in the range (-10, 10))

Comment: Just to give another example where the inverse clearly exists: if f(x) = x^5 + c, f^(-1)(x) = (x - c)^(1/5).  Maybe it's possible to identify the subset of polynomials (maybe stricter than just monotonic) where this kind of inverse can be found.  Or at least find a test for whether whether a polynomial is in the set.

Answer (score 1):

Given a function :
$$y(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + a_3 x^3 + a_4 x^4 + a_5 x^5$$
such as $x$ and $y$ be real and the relationship be one-to-one, the inverse function $x(y)$ is the real root of the equation :
$$A_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + a_3 x^3 + a_4 x^4 + a_5 x^5=0\quad\text{where}\quad A_0=(a_0-y)$$
This is the quintic equation : 
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuinticEquation.html

In general (except for some particular values of the coefficients) the analytical solving for $x$ is not possible in terms of a finite number of elementary functions.

So, don't expect a non-iterative approche if you exclue the use of a convenient special function.

In the present case, the special functions involved are the Jacobi theta functions :
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiThetaFunctions.html

This is an **arduous** analytical calculus. See the formal solution in  http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuinticEquation.html

On a practical viewpoint the use of numerical calculus is much simpler, but of course it doesn't satisfy your wish of non-iterative method.

Comment: My hope was that even though quintic equations don't have closed-form roots in general, it would still be possible to find them in a relatively simple way due to monotonicity, (and hence uniqueness of the real root) in my special case. However, if that's not possible, then my question is answered I guess.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quintic_function#Solvable_quintics summarizes quintics that are "solvable" with radicals.  The category of monotonic quintics isn't mentioned as such. 
 My amateur guess is your solution is in there but would take a bit of work to find, understand, and finally apply each time. Maybe one hint is that *any* solution to a monotonic quintic is *the* solution.  A good first guess and Newton's method is the easiest path for me.